# How to limit php-fpm.log size on Mac?

Tags: php, macos-catalina

The `php-pfm.log` is huge:

```
$ pwd
/usr/local/var/log
$ ls -al
total 117932040
drwxr-xr-x  5 ohho  admin          160 Dec 10  2018 .
drwxrwxr-x  9 ohho  admin          288 Dec  5 18:16 ..
drwxr-xr-x  4 ohho  admin          128 Dec 10  2018 nginx
-rw-r--r--  1 ohho  admin  60377103556 Dec  5 12:10 php-fpm.log
-rw-r--r--  1 ohho  admin            0 Dec  4 09:21 php-fpm.log.default
```

I install `php` and `nginx` via `homebrew`:

```
$ which php-fpm
/usr/local/sbin/php-fpm
$ php-fpm --version
PHP 7.4.0 (fpm-fcgi) (built: Nov 29 2019 16:18:54)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.0, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
$ php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php/7.4
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php/7.4/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/7.4/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/7.4/conf.d/ext-opcache.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/7.4/conf.d/php-memory-limits.ini
```

Is there an option to limit the size of the `php-fpm.log`?

Comment: Use `logrotate`.

Comment: Does `log_errors_max_length` have any effect? https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php